# How do we get the solution?

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

We have the problem \begin{align*}&u_t+uu_x=0 \\ &u(x,0)=\begin{cases}2, & x<0 \\ 2-x, & x\in[0,1]  \\1, & x>1\end{cases}\end{align*} We have the problems $$\frac{dx}{dt}=u \ \text{ and } \ \frac{du}{dt}=0$$ From the first one we get $x=ct+c_2$ and for $t=0$ we get $x_0=c_2$ and so we get $x_0=x-ct$.

From the second one we get $$\frac{dx}{dt}=u(x,t)=u(x_0,0)=\begin{cases}2, & x_0<0 \\ 2-x_0, & x_0\in[0,1]  \\1 , & x_0>1\end{cases}$$ Solving for $x_0$ we get $$x_0=\begin{cases}x-2t, & x<2t \\ \frac{2t-x}{t-1}, & \frac{2t-x}{t-1} \in [0.1] \\ x-t, & x>t\end{cases}$$ So, $u$ is equal to $$u=\begin{cases}2, & x<2t \\ 2-\frac{2t-x}{t-1}, & \frac{x-2}{t-1}\in[0,1]  \\1 , & x>t\end{cases}=\begin{cases}2, & x<2t \\ \frac{x-2}{t-1}, & \frac{x-2}{t-1}\in[0,1]  \\1 , & x>t\end{cases}$$ For $t<1$ we get $$u=\begin{cases}2, & x<2t \\ \frac{x-2}{t-1}, & 2t\leq x\leq t+1  \\1 , & x>t\end{cases}$$ and for $t\geq 1$ we get $$u=\begin{cases}2, & x<2t \\ \frac{x-2}{t-1}, & t+1\leq x\leq 2t  \\1 , & x>t\end{cases}$$ This can be simplified into $$u=\begin{cases}2, & x<2t  \\1 , & x>t\end{cases}$$ or not?

According to the solution the case $t\geq 1$ is  $$u=\begin{cases}2, & x<\frac{3}{2}t+\frac{1}{2}  \\1 , & x>\frac{3}{2}t+\frac{1}{2}\end{cases}$$ But how do we get the inequalities with $\frac{3}{2}t+\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Also, could you tell me why for $t<1$ we have a classical solution, but for $t>1$ a weak one?

Comment: One small point, in the last line of your initial conditions, I think you mean $x>1$.

Comment: @bob.sacamento Yes, you are right... I edited it. Do you have an idea about my question?

Comment: I kept thinking about this because it's an interesting problem.  I follow you up to your solution for $u$ with $t<1$.  Then I get lost.  At $t=1$ all of the characteristics in this problem "collide" and the solution becomes singular at $x=2$.  After that, it is multivalued over an ever-increasing range of $x$.  I have no idea how your text gets the solution it gets, or any solution at all.  Very sorry.  Well, the "envelope" containing that middle range is bounded by $x=2t$ and $x=t+1$.  Looks like the line $x=3/2t+1/2$ is the "average" of those two lines.  Are you supposed to know to use that?